# "It's time everyone had access" or "It's time everyone has access"

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence gramatically correct?

> We think it's time everyone *had* access to the means of media production so we have developed a set of tools for it.

Or should I use *has* instead?

> We think it's time everyone *has* access to the means of media production so we have developed a set of tools for it.

Does it affect the meaning?

Comment: Compare *"It's time we went home"* and *"It's time we **go** home"*. I think this is General Reference for ELU.

Comment: @Fumble: I'm sorry—as I'm not a native speaker, I can't compare. If you think the question is GR, so be it, but I honestly don't know the difference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is my [interpretation](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/108133/9097) correct?

Comment: Your question *(which form is "correct"?)* is easily answered by any native speaker, and perhaps would have been better posed on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). As to *why* we use that verb tense, I'm not really sure. Essentially, it's idiomatic, but my guess is it's a form of subjunctive, which [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood) says is *called the **past subjunctive** when referring counterfactually to the present*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I disagree. It is not "easily answered by native speakers," since even you yourself say in the very next sentence, "I'm not really sure [why]."

Comment: @Octopus: The matter of "Which is correct?" (i.e. - "Which form do native speakers invariably prefer?", being the question as asked) is very different to the matter of *why* we use the form we do. Any supposed difference in meaning is non-existent/irrelevant, imho. The reason itself is really a matter of **idiomatic usage** - witness the fact that non-native speakers are [stereo]typically inclined to to say *"It's time we go home"*, whereas native speakers *never* say that.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603360/2085).

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it.

The first sentence is like a slogan—it *doesn't assert* that everyone actually had or has access but argues that *it's time* for everyone to gain this access.

The second sentence *asserts* that everyone has access.

In this context, the first sentence fits better because its second part (“we have developed the tools”) answers the goal described in the first part (“it's time everyone had access”).

Think:

> It's time everyone had access to better Q&A sites, so we made Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

This is the *subjunctive*. You can find quite a few instances of it in 19th century literature with Google. For example, Sir Walter Scott used [it is time I were returning](http://books.google.com/books?id=XaQ9AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA285&lpg=PA285&dq=%22It+is+time+I+were%22&source=bl&ots=hfybpHbry2&sig=X9v9LI3hrkMm80MS0QrYuQzO_Vk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BllLUc-KDamK0QHHyYHABg&ved=0CDoQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=%22It%20is%20time%20I%20were%22&f=false) in *Waverly*.

Is the meaning different? Technically, there should be a small difference in the meaning, but I don't believe anybody actually makes this distinction nowadays.

Since the *were*-subjunctive is slowly dying in English, and since this sounds to me like a particularly archaic instance of it, I would recommend just using the indicative.

Comment: So [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/108133/9097) isn't a correct interpretation?

Comment: @Dan: Your interpretation might be correct if people actually used the indicative and the subjunctive properly. But they don't. If I heard either of these, I'd assume that it meant that it's time for everybody to gain access.

Answer (score 0):

The *has* version sounds more natural to me.
Look at the verbs' diff forms [here](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/verbtohave.html).